# a maintainable way to validate keys/values in a JSON like property map

Tags: java, json, oop, validation

I am writing a java program to validate keys and values in a property map, which could treat as a JSON object. Right now I am using deeply nested if-else to validate that but it's crazy error-prone. Not sure if this could be easily solved in any design pattern.

Take player property map for example:

```
'player' = {'name': 'player1', 
            'age': 18, 
            'race': 'human',
            'skills': 'pick pocket',
            'misc': { 'hoppy': 'sleep', 'exp': 238459 }
           };
```

I want to validate few things

- Some key-value pairs are mandatory: like `name` is mandatory in `player` property map, `misc` is not.
- Some values need to be specific type, like value of `age` need
  to be an integer.
- Some values are enum, like `race` could be `human`, `elf`, `drawf` but nothing else.
- Some keys depend on other keys, if `A` key is specified, then `B` key also need to be specified. Like if `country` depends on `'race': 'human'`, so `{'race': 'human', 'country': 'midearth'}` is valid. `{'race': 'human', 'enemy': 'ghost'}`, `{'race': 'human'}` are not.
- Values could be maps as well, values in that map don't need to be same type.

This property map will be extended in the future. What design would make it more extendable?

Comment: This is a problem that has been solved many times; [Google protobufs](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) comes to mind.

Comment: Everything you want to do can be achieved with XML.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the Java class. You can reduce much of your effort by using JSR-303 validation annotaions.

Example :-

```
class Player{

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=5,max=200)
    private String name;

    @Min(value=10)
    @Max(value=60)
    private int age;

    .
    .
    . // other fields
}
```

Find available validation annotations [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html) and tutorial [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/bean-validation-made-simple).

Applying the validation on Java bean instead of JSON string/object will be better approach in my opinion.

Converting the bean from and to JSON string is easier using [Google's GSON API](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)